# How can I view older notification messages?

Tags: support, notifications

Am using IE 8 at work; when I have messages, sometimes clicking on the messages icon/label/down arrow does not do anything, sometimes it does.  Seems to help if I first click on a message.  But my real question is about the case of having 2 or more messages; after I click on and read the first one, I do not know how to find the second one.  The indicator says I don't have any messages, and I don't know any way to get a list of messages, not even a list of recent messages.  Is there a UI thing I'm missing here somewhere?

Comment: IE8 is no longer supported.

Comment: *2013*..... *using IE8*... is this browser considered a virus yet ?

Comment: I have no doubt it is, at least by some, but my company has things locked down and this is what they let me use.  And they really don't care much about stackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the "inbox" link

[image]

This will present you with a list of all of your notifications, most recent first.

Comment: I've marked the first and more complete answer; all this time using this system and I had missed where an "inbox" link even was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rcook If you're looking to accept the first answer, note that Jim was ahead of me by a few minutes, 18:52:01 vs. 18:55:31.  Don't forget that answers with an equal number of votes are ordered randomly by default.

Comment: @blah I hadn't forgotten -- I never knew.  Thanks for pointing it out, I've re-marked it for the real first answer.

Comment: @rcook There's been a lot of discussion surrounding this.  Check out [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731) for the most significant stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe IE8 is an oddball in this regard, but the easiest way is to simply pull down the messages tab and select the inbox:
[image]

If the notifications were about answers or comments you can also go to [the responses tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013112/rcook?tab=responses).

The information about other notifications will generally be available somewhere in your profile, but those are the main two spots.